# How can I make the same session function on both "mysite.com" and "www.mysite.com"?

Tags: php

I am having a problem over and over where a member is logged into my site using www. and if he accesses a link without www., the session variables don't carry over.

What's the way to make them both access the same place?

Comment: Perhaps you should not bring them over to www.*, but rather redirect all traffic to any of them to one of them?

Answer (score 5):

### Ideal

Your site should reside on [one canonical domain](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066). So you should pick either `www.` or the top level domain and change all your links so that they point to one web address. It would be wise to switch to setting the domain in a configuration and using that to create web addresses across your application - this way you can easily change the URL later if you wish.

If you are running Apache you can also easily redirect traffic from one domain to the other by adding the following to the `.htaccess` file of your site:

```
#enforce the use of the www. subdomain on the sites URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^(www.).*$                 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$        http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1  [R=301,L]
```

I should also mention that there is a growing movement away from using the `www.` subdomain as the main "URL" for a site. See: http://no-www.org/index.php

### Less ideal

You change the cookie configuration when you set it so that it will work across domains. This is described on the [`setcookie()` manual page](http://php.net/set_cookie) with the `domain` parameter:

> The domain that the cookie is available to. Setting the domain to
>   'www.example.com' will make the cookie available in the www subdomain
>   and higher subdomains. Cookies available to a lower domain, such as
>   'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as
>   'www.example.com'. Older browsers still implementing the deprecated »
>   RFC 2109 may require a leading . to match all subdomains.

The only issue with this is that your site will still be accessible via two URLs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply bud, I'll have a play around with this and get back to you. If it works, I'll give it the green tick!

Comment: Please provide a citation for the term "growing" used in your answer. There has not been a post on that website since 2008, and even then it was just one since 2005. ISTR that no-www was the centre of attention for the movement, and cleary it's hardly a hub of activity.

Comment: Citation? Shall I knock up a blog post and link to it? :) Seriously most of the new services and applications I have seen launched over the past few years have been without the `www.` for example Twitter, GitHub, Forrst, __Stack Overflow__, Posterous, Flattr etc and even the recently contraversial AllThis.com. As each site launches without `www.` the number grows so I don't really see your point here. I am not suggesting one method is more popular than the other. Quite the opposite is true: http://toolbar.netcraft.com/stats/topsites of the top websites on the web! :)

Answer (score 4):

Solution 1: Set the cookie's domain to the domain name without the www prefix (this way both requests should be sent with the cookie data).

Solution 2: Redirect everyone using the variant without the prefix to the one with the prefix (e.g. using mod_rewrite).

Answer (score 0):

Modify your server configuration to 301 redirect traffic from 'yourdomain.com' to 'www.yourdomain.com'

Answer (score 0):

when some user access the www.* site, redirect then to the other site automatically

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You can choose to direct either way and there is a growing movement away from using `www.` as the main domain for a site: http://no-www.org/index.php

Comment: @Treffynnon: Yes, I'm perfectly well aware of that movement of [fools](http://www.yes-www.org/www-is-not-deprecated/). I'd hardly call it "growing".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You aren't helping your argument here with name calling - your initial comment implied that it could not be done, which we both now agree is incorrect. I couldn't give a stuff if it has `www.` or not just pick one and redirect to it! :) Stack Overflow, GitHub, Twitter etc all have no `www.` BTW so I am not sure where you get the idea that this is irregular.

Comment: @Treffynnon: I did not call anybody names. I made an observation that, with a link to rationale, followers of the antiquated "no-www" movement are foolish. Name-calling is when you say "hey, stupid-face!". Also I did not say it is "irregular", and I also never said that it "could not be done" -- I've been redirecting URLs for many, many years. I said that he got it the "wrong way around", because the "correct" advice and best approach is to keep the "www.". But I enjoyed your strawman. Very tasty.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit please could you show me the research that backs up this claim? I am happy to be proven wrong, but all I see here is opinion and the potential to mislead with a curt opening statement that implies something won't work. Like I say, it bothers me not which way people go as long as they pick one and redirect to it from their other domains.

Comment: @Treffynnon: You're probably going to try to claim this as some sort of "win", but you know what? I'm not going to continue this conversation because I can already see where it's headed, and I've had quite enough of that on SO recently.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No it's actually a disappointment. I was genuinely hoping to see some research on this topic. It is something that is always asked about and I had hoped that you would be referring to material that would put a nail in that pointless conversations coffin. I have nothing against either `yes-www`ers or `no-www`ers. BTW I think we may have had a similar discussion (different topic) when you were known as Tomalak Geret'kal.

Comment: It's always going to be subjective, but your assertion that it is a "growing movement" and mine that followers of said movement are "fools" are equal in weight in the absence of proof of research on either side. We might as well leave it there. :) _[though that doesn't work quite as well when you use it as an assertion as part of an answer; see my comment on yours]_

Comment: TBH had I have known that you had changed your name before starting this discussion I probably would have avoided commenting all together with the knowledge of our previous interaction! :) Like you say locking horns on SO doesn't serve anybody.